# Jest/Enzyme test failing after simulate('submit') "this.props.searchUser is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

> FAIL  client/containers/Users/userListContainer.test.js
>     ●  tests › Should show User after a user searches

#### Expected

After simulated click, test to find 2 li's in container should pass

#### Results

Getting > this.props.searchUser is not a function

### userListContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { UserList } from '../../components'

// Actions
import { searchUser } from '../../actions'

export class UserListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e, user) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.searchUser(user)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='users-container'>
                <UserList
                    users={this.props.users}
                    lastUserSearched={this.props.lastUserSearched}
                    onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.usersReducer.users,
        lastUserSearched: state.usersReducer.lastUserSearched
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        searchUser: (user) => {dispatch(searchUser(user))},
    }
}

const userList = UserListContainer;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(userList)
```

### UserList action

```
import * as actionTypes from '../../actionTypes'

export const searchUser = (user) => ({
  type: actionTypes.SEARCH_USER,
  payload: user
});
```

### Test Code

```
import React from 'react'
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import { UserListContainer } from './UserListContainer'
import userList from './UserListContainer'

const userListContainer = shallow(<UserListContainer />);

describe('<UserListContainer /> tests', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<UserListContainer />);
    });

    it('Should render', () => {
        const tree = toJson(userList);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('Should show User after a user searches', () => {
        wrapper.find('form label input').get(0).value = "ni";
        // console.log('wrapper', wrapper)
        wrapper.find('form label button.btn-blue').simulate('submit');
        expect(wrapper.find('ul li')).toHaveLength(2);
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in props to your `UserListContainer` in your test, including your `searchUser` function. The `connect` isn't going to get it for you in your test. Abramov himself actually suggests you don't test the `connect`

```
 beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<UserListContainer searchUser={() => {}} />);
 });
```

If I may suggest, you might be better off making this test more 'unit' like. For example, you might `shallow` mount `UserList` and simulate the click, and merely spy on the function to make sure it is called. You can then shallow mount it again with different props which would simulate any changes occurring. Likewise, in your container, you could just call `onFormSubmit` and make sure that `searchUser` is called.

Comment: Thanks, checking this answer as I am no longer getting the error `this.props.searchUser is not a function` however I'm getting a giant object instead of the expected 2 li's. I added a screenshot at the bottom of my question to show what I mean. Also here is a new question if you have additional time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225660/jest-enzyme-test-fails-to-find-lis-after-store-dispatch-action-is-called